# GainNode.gain.value return property gain undefined?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm learning Web Audio API. I'm trying to recreate the example on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GainNode).

Here is my code:

```
const playBtn = document.getElementById('play');
const pauseBtn = document.getElementById('pause');
const gainBtn = document.getElementById('gain');
const myAudio = document.getElementById('myAudio');
const file = 'https://iondrimbafilho.me/second-demo.mp3';

const request = new XMLHttpRequest();    
request.open('GET', file, true);

request.onload = () => {
  myAudio.src = file;
  myAudio.load();
}

let audioCtx;
let source;
let gainNode;

document.onload = () => {
  audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
  source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(myAudio);
  gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();
  source.connect(gainNode)
  gainNode.connect(audioCtx.destination)
}

playBtn.onclick = () => {
  myAudio.play()
};

gainBtn.onclick = () => {
  console.log(gainNode.gain.value)
};
```

I connect the source node to the `GainNode`, which then connected to the destination node.

I'm trying to log the audio gain.
But why is the property `GainNode.gain` undefined?

Here is the error I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'gain' of undefined
    at HTMLButtonElement.gainBtn.onclick
```

Additional info: I'm using Chrome 78.

Comment: Because `gainNode` is undefined at this time.

Comment: @TGrif Even after I clicked `playBtn`?

Comment: It is undefined because `document.onload` is never called. Try with `window.onload`.